# Using Touch and Click annotations for same button

Tags: java, android, android-annotations

I am using android-annotations for a sample project and trying to learn it, but i came up with a strange thing.

Assume that we have a simple button named "@+id/button"

Now i want to write two seperate methods for touch and click events.

```
@Touch
public void button(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        v.setAlpha(0.5f);
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        v.setAlpha(1f);
    }
}

@Click
public void button() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

When i run the project, i see the touch event, but click event will never be caught. Am i missing something, may be conceptual ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method annotated by @Touch can return an boolean indicating whether the event is consumed. So you can replace the method

```
@Touch
public void button(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

by

```
@Touch
public boolean button(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ...
    return false;
}
```